# Qualtrics Loop and Merge Non Consecutive

Tags: loops, random, survey, qualtrics

I have a cumbersome Qualtrics question about combining randomization and Loop & Merge. I have 2 groups of 20 questions. The 20 questions are just variations of the same question so I can use Loop and Merge to display those 20 questions within each group. However, I need questions to be randomly displayed across groups.

Illustrating example:

```
Group A: How did __ do with x. 
Q1A: Martha
Q2A: David
Q3A: Paul

Group B: When did ___ help you out?. 
Q1B: Joan 
Q2B: Henry
Q3B: Kelly
```

Right now I can use loop and merge to optimize the process within each question. However, if I add a randomizer what is randomized is if Group A or Group B is displayed first. Instead, what I need is for all the questions to be randomly displayed. Example:

```
When did Henry help you out.
When did Kelly help you out.
How did Martha do with x.
When did Joan help you out.
How did Paul do with x.
How did David do with x.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could put both questions in 1 loop and merge, and then add display logic to each, to only show when the loop is in the appropriate list.

Unfortunately this type of display logic is not currently supported by the JFE, so it will revert to the SE.

Alternatively, you can setup each question individually in their own blocks (not using loop and merge), and randomize in the survey flow.